# Installing Oracle Virtualbox error

Tags: virtualbox

When I tried to install 'Oracle VM Virtual Box' it is giving a error -`VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. Certain guest (e.g. OS/2 and QNX) require this feature and will fail to boot without it.`

My processor is - Intel Pentium dual CPU E2160. If it is not possible in this processor then can you kindly let me know the processor  numbers that will support this software,

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that CPU does not support Virtualization technology,  if you are looking for Intel processors that support it look at this list [here](http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology)

If it Supports Intel® VT-x, and once it is enabled in the bios you will be able to use Virtualbox with Hardware Acceleration